# filter_var for FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL results in unknown error

Tags: php, validation

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with the call to `filter_var` in `validateEmail` function below? If I comment the line `hohum` can be seen in FireBug or Chrome console, on the other hand Chrome reports something like: `This request has no response`. Coming from java background, I wonder if I need to `include` some library for the filter_var function?

```
<?php

function validateInput($data, $con) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data);
  return $data;
}

function validateEmail($email, $con) {
   $email = validateInput($email, $con);
   if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) {
      return $email;
   } else {
      return "";
   }
}

function validateText($text, $con) {
    $text = validateInput($text, $con);
    if(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $text) == 0) {
        return $text;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
 }

 $hostname="localhost";
 $username="my_user";
 $password="my_psswd";
 $dbname="my_db";
 $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);


 if (!$con) {
    header('HTTP', true, 500);
    echo('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 } else {
    echo ("Hohum: ");
 }
?>
```

Comment: Or maybe it's just the syntax error. Enable `error_reporting` *before* invoking the script.

Comment: Sidenote: Mixing APIs with `mysql_error()` - *"Gin & tonic my good man!"*. Wait, scratch that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `)`,

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

Comment: I need to use some IDE instead of Notepad++